# Given $\{f_n\}$ uniformly bounded and $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $S.$ Prove $\frac{f_1 + f_2 + \cdots + f_n}{n} \to f$ uniformly on $S.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

I know this is equivalent to showing $\dfrac{f_1 + f_2 + \cdots + f_n} n - f \to 0$.

And in turn $\dfrac{(f_1 - f) + (f_2  - f) + \cdots + (f_n - f)}{n} \to 0$.

I can split the fraction as follows:

$$\frac{(f_1 - f) + (f_2  - f) + \cdots + (f_N - f)}{n} + \frac{(f_{N+1} - f) + (f_{N+2}  - f) + \cdots + (f_n - f)} n \to 0.$$

In the first fraction, the numerator differences are bounded, and there are finite terms, so it goes to zero. I am unsure how to prove the remaining $n-N$ terms in the second fraction are bounded, though.

Is it as simple as saying that because we know that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $S$, we can choose $N$ large enough such that each difference will be less than $\frac{\epsilon}{n-N}$, and the sum of the $n-N$ remaining difference terms will be less than $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 2):

Given $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an index $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
|f_j(x) - f(x)| < \varepsilon
\qquad \forall j>N,\ \forall x.
$$
If $C>0$ is a constant such that $|f_j(x)| \leq C$ for every $j$ and $x$, using your notation you get, for every $n>N$,
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n |f_j - f| \leq
\frac{C\, N}{n} + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=N+1}^n |f_j-f|
\leq
\frac{C\, N}{n} + \varepsilon \frac{n-N}{n}
$$
hence
$$
0\leq \limsup_n \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n |f_j - f| \leq \varepsilon.
$$
Finally, since this inequality holds for every $\varepsilon> 0$, you conclude  that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n |f_j - f|$ converges uniformly to $0$.